# Why does istream can read a file but not close it?

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword, ifstream, istream

I have class `Matrix` (defined below), and in this this class I'm overloading the operator >>. I first did it by using `ifstream` which gave the following:
The class:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int _rows{};
    int _cols{};
    float *_arrData{};
public:
    // Constructors

    Matrix(int rows, int cols);
    friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& s, const Matrix& mat);
}
```

Definition of the operator >> :

```
std::ifstream &operator>>(std::ifstream &s, const Matrix &mat)
{
    s.read((char*)mat._arrData, sizeof(float) * mat._rows * mat._cols);
    if (!s)
    {
        std::cerr << FILE_ERR << std::endl;
        s.close();
        exit(ERROR);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Which is working perfectly fine.
Now, when trying to use `istream`, I would have written the same, but the compiler would throw me an error telling me that istream has no member named `close`. Why ? How come I could read the file with istream but couldn't close it ? Why would we even allow such action ? (Note that the fstream class is included)

Comment: There exists [`std::ifstream::close`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close). Please provide [mre].

Comment: The standard doesn't impose streams to be closeable. This is a property of files. You can easily implement a stream of an endless integer sequence.

Comment: I did include fstream yes

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius please tell me what should I add ? I think my example is pretty exhaustive

Comment: To end a stream you can use `setstate()` to set the eof flag.

Comment: Side note, a `<<` or `>>` operator shouldn't close the file. They should just return the failed stream state and leave the decision making to the caller. `>>` has a very simple job, and by adding extra responsibilities you've made it so that the stream cannot recover from simple errors.

Comment: @ThomasSablik as I've written in the first two lines, I first used ifstream, which then led to the question: why does istream can't do the same

Comment: Now I get it. You don't know polymorphism. You created a `ifstream` and passed it as `istream` reference.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Correct, not in cpp at least

Comment: `s` is referencing a `ifstream` object in your special case. You should read about polymorphism first. It's very important at this point. You can start here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects

Comment: Does that mean that the function close is only implemented in the ifstream class, which is a sub-class of istream ?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason you can't call it. You could dynamic_cast `s` to an `ifstream` reference and call `close`. You could even static_cast it if you're sure that it's always an `ifstream` object.

Comment: @MM1 "_please tell me what should I add ?_" Did you read the link? It will explain how the [mre] should look. For instance: we, currently, can't copy-paste the example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not my first post here, and as mentioned in the question, there is only one line to change in order to get the problem. In view of the comments, it seems to me that there was no issue as to the understanding of the problem.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- of course, "if you're sure that it's always an `ifstream` object", then the function should take an `ifstream&` and not an `istream&`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I started my comment with the part about dynamic_cast and it was kind of wrong without referencing static_cast. The wording could be better.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- the wording is fine. It address how to convert. My comment is a frame challenge.

Comment: @PeteBecker I described the `dynamic_cast` and because many people don't know I wanted to say that there technically is the option to upcast a reference with `static_cast`. But I didn't want to say that this is a use case for a `static_cast`.